# Split on more than one space?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a program that needs to split lines that are of the format:

```
IDNumber      Firstname Lastname    GPA      Credits
```

but I want to keep `Firstname` and `Lastname` in the same string.

Is there any easy way to do this (other than just splitting into five strings instead of four) and somehow have the split method only split when there is more than one space?

Comment: Split by 2 spaces? - actually this is a suggestion. But I'd split ti on one space anr rejoin items 1 and 2.

Comment: 2 _or more_ spaces

Comment: Use regex; `re.split` on `r'\s{2,}'` (two or more whitespace characters).

Comment: What do you expect as a result?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: also https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/jzpo5/when_your_program_asks_for_a_first_name_or_last/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to split by *any* whitespace, you can use `str.split`:

```
mystr.split()

# ['IDNumber', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'GPA', 'Credits']
```

For *two or more* spaces:

```
list(filter(None, mystr.split('  ')))

# ['IDNumber', 'Firstname Lastname', 'GPA', 'Credits']
```

Answer (score 17):

Use regex to split on *two or more spaces*:

```
>>> re.split(r" {2,}", s)
['IDNumber', 'Firstname Lastname', 'GPA', 'Credits']
```

If you want to split on two or more *white-space characters generally*, then use:

```
re.split(r"\s{2,}", s)
```

e.g.:

```
>>> s = "hello, world\t\tgoodbye cruel world"
>>> print(s)
hello, world        goodbye cruel world
>>> re.split(r"\s{2,}", s)
['hello, world', 'goodbye cruel world']
```

Comment: This is the true answer