# Check if value exists in array with python, append if not

Tags: python, arrays, json, for-loop, txt

I am scraping from a txt file, and adding to an array. I've written a for loop to 1. take an entry from the txt file, 2. check if it exists in the results array, and if not 3. add it to the results array.

data.txt looks like this:

```
0100002159900000000000       Sales              Deval Patrick               Seattle
0100003159900000000000       Sales              Bernie Sanders              Chicago
0100004159900000000000       Sales              Joseph R. Biden             Dallas
0100005159900000000000       Marketing          Michael R. Bloomberg        Boston
...etc.
```

results array should look like this:

```
employees = [
        {
            "dept": "Sales",
            "remote": False,
            "management": [
                {
                    "manager": "Smith",
                    "level": "county",
                    "people": [
                         {
                              "first_name": "Deval",
                              "middle_name": "",
                              "last_name": "Patrick",
                              "city": Seattle,
                         },
                         {
                              "first_name": "Bernie",
                              "middle_name": "",
                              "last_name": "Sanders",
                              "city": Chicago,
                         },
                         {
                              "first_name": "Joseph",
                              "middle_name": "R",
                              "last_name": "Biden",
                              "city": Dallas,
                         },
                    ]
                },
                
            ]
        },
        {
            "dept": "Marketing",
            "remote": True,
            "management": [
                {
                    "manager": "Jones",
                    "level": "county",
                    "people": [
                         {
                              "first_name": "Michael",
                              "middle_name": "R",
                              "last_name": "Bloomberg",
                              "city": Boston,
                         }
                    ]
                },
                ...etc.
                
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I'm struggling with the if logic of "if this isn't in the array, add it." Here's what I have right now:

```
employees = []
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    for row in data:
        # splits row by an instance of two or more characters of white space
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917121/split-on-more-than-one-space
        row = re.split(r"\s{2,}", row)
        empl_id = row[0]
        empl_name = row[2]
        empl_dept = row[1]

        for item in employees:
            current_dept = item['dept']
            if empl_dept != current_dept:
                    
                # create/append dept object:
                dept_obj = {
                     "dept": "Sales",
                     "remote": False,
                     "management": [
                          {
                               "manager": "Smith",
                               "level": "county",
                               "people": []
                          }
                      ]
                 }
                 employees.append(dept_obj)

            else: # if dept_object does exist
                #add people object:
                employees[current_dept]['management']['people'].append({
                     "empl_name": empl_name,
                     "empl_id": empl_id
                })
```

I know this logic and probably some of the syntax is wrong. My main current issue is that it is adding an dept_obj for every single item in the employees array, which keeps getting bigger and bigger obviously. I'm sure there's a better way to write this, I just don't know what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: might want to look at collections.defaultdict. I find it useful for this sort of "create/append" situations

The real question is how do you know how to define the new dept when you need one?

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.