# Split a string variable into lines based on space between characters

Tags: python

I have a string variable (text) which looks like the following:

```
text = 'Be specific and      imagine you’re   asking a question    to another         person'
```

There are random spaces (in terms of character length) between the words of the string. I want to split the string variable in lines in such a way, that when there is a space between 2 words bigger than 3 characters (or spaces) the remainder of the string gets split and pasted 2 lines below. Also, I want the part of the string that gets split to begin from the start of the line (and not have the space characters in the beginning of the line).
So the end result should be:

```
'Be specific and      

imagine you’re   

asking a question    

to another         

person'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split on more than one space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917121/split-on-more-than-one-space)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re
text = 'Be specific and      imagine you’re   asking a question    to another         person'

for item in re.split(r" {2,}", text):
    print(item)
```